# Why my timer is not starting at all and how it should stop?

Tags: java, android

I have a thread with a runnable:

```
Thread serverChecksThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {   
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            Looper l = Looper.myLooper();
            customHandler = new Handler(l);
            customHandler.postDelayed(serverChecksRunnable, 0);
            Looper.loop();
        }
});

Runnable serverChecksRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (connectedSuccess == true) {
                checkServer = Get(iptouse + "uploadstatus");
        }

        Handler h=new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (connectedSuccess) {
                    if (checkServer != null) {
                        String a = null;
                        try {
                            a = new String(checkServer, "UTF-8");
                            textforthespeacch = a;
                            if (textforthespeacch.contains("upload completed")) {
                                String varr = textforthespeacch.substring(17);
                                String varr1 = textforthespeacch.substring(0, 16);
                                textforthespeacch = varr1;
                                status1.setText("Upload completed" + " " + varr + "%");
                                numberofuploadedfilescounter += 1;
                                uploadedfilescount.setText(("Uploaded Files: " + numberofuploadedfilescounter));
                                MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                            }
                            if (textforthespeacch.contains("uploading") {
                                String[] split = textforthespeacch.split(" ");
                                textforthespeacch = split[0];
                                status1.setText("Uploading" + " " + split[1] + "%");
                                updateTimerThread.start();
                                servercheckCounter += 1;
                                if (servercheckCounter == 1) {
                                    MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        customHandler.postDelayed(serverChecksRunnable,1000);
    }
});
```

The timer thread:

```
Thread updateTimerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            long updatedTime = 0L;
            long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

What I want to do is start the timer when the uploading starts.  Then when the upload finishes stop the timer.

In the Runnable I added:

```
updateTimerThread.start();
```

Right after I set my text to "uploading"

In the Runnable when it gets to the "upload completed" line:

```
status1.setText("Upload completed" + " " + varr + "%");
```

I want the timer to stop so I can see the amount of time that each file took to upload.

The problem is that when it start the timer thread the program crash i used a break point and can't find why.

Secondly, how should I get the timer to stop?  Will it stop automatically once the code is gets to the "upload completed" line? Then on the next file upload how can I get the timer to reset and start over again (That's why I need that on each "uploading" state the time will be reset and start over again, and then will stop again on the "upload completed" state.

This is the logcat:

```
09-14 15:36:59.385    2103-2103/com.test.webservertest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.webservertest, PID: 2103
    java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started
            at java.lang.Thread.checkNotStarted(Thread.java:849)
            at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1059)
            at com.test.webservertest.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:251)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

Comment: According to the exception if i understand it right i need to stop somehow the updateTimerThread. When i'm uploading a file it start the thread i need somehow in the part where the upload finished to stop the thread or kill it and then on the next upload to start it again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to upload file ?, then use this [Android Upload Service](https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service). Easily upload files in the background with automatic Android Notification Center progress indication

```
public void upload(final Context context) {
final UploadRequest request = new UploadRequest(context,
                                                "custom-upload-id",
                                                "http://www.yoursite.com/yourscript");

/*
 * parameter-name: is the name of the parameter that will contain file's data.
 * Pass "uploaded_file" if you're using the test PHP script
 *
 * custom-file-name.extension: is the file name seen by the server.
 * E.g. value of $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"] of the test PHP script
 */
request.addFileToUpload("/absolute/path/to/your/file",
                        "parameter-name",
                        "custom-file-name.extension",
                        "content-type"));

 try {
    //Start upload service and display the notification
    UploadService.startUpload(request);

 } catch (Exception exc) {
    //You will end up here only if you pass an incomplete UploadRequest
    Log.e("AndroidUploadService", exc.getLocalizedMessage(), exc);
 }

}
```